# How to get a date in My SQL in MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.S edt/est format

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get the date to display in My sql in the formats shown in the following examples?

```
 "02/23/2012 13:46:20.5 EST"
```

OR

```
"03/23/2012 13:46:20.5 EDT"
```

Basically I am looking for something that can include time zone in the formatted string

Comment: Store the date as a timestamp and store the timezone in a different column. Then use the server side language of your choice to format it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Store all times in UTC (Zulu time, aka GMT) and then use `CONVERT_TZ` in MySQL to convert to whatever time zone you want.